# Deployment of Bndtools Projects in Hudson

Tags: deployment, hudson, bndtools

Since I am a big fan of developing OSGi with Bndtools. I want to use it for my new project request as well. But one requirement is that all build processes should be done by Hudson.

My question is how I can achieve that I can use Hudson connected to my Bndtools projects? Maybe someone has a step-by-step tutorial for me :) Furthermore, will Hudson use OBR to resolve the dependencies like Bndtools is doing? How should such a deploy process look like? Btw Bndtools has its one "Integrated Test" project environment where it starts an OSGi environment in the background. Will Hudson understand such kind of tests?

What is best practice to use as much as possible of Bndtools?

Thanks for any help.

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by just iterate with a custom main build.xml through each projects build.xml. I works and it's nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new build task in hudson and define there ant build steps rather than introducing and maintaining a new build file.
Create for each project an ant build step.

In my case I created a task named BuildAll which has several ant build steps in it.